# How can I configure AutoMapper to convert all collections of reference types to collections of integers?

Tags: c#, automapper, dto, boilerplate

Let's say I have the following entity:

```
public class Store
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public List<Camera> Cameras { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, a `Store` that has `Products`, `Employees`, and security `Cameras`. I want to convert this `Store` to a `StoreDTO`:

```
public class StoreDTO
{
    public List<int> ProductIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> EmployeeIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> CameraIds { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, the `StoreDTO` will only have the entity IDs.

Right now, I'm using this code to set up `AutoMapper`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, int>().ConvertUsing(x => x.Id);
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, int>().ConvertUsing(x => x.Id);
Mapper.CreateMap<Camera, int>().ConvertUsing(x => x.Id);
```

As you can see, it's a lot of boilerplate code. Is there any way to configure `AutoMapper` to automatically convert **all** collections of reference types to collections of integers?

Comment: you could also use valueinjecter and create just one injection which is gonna map from id to an int and use for whatever type you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this with a bit of LINQ over reflection.  You can use LINQ to query all types that derive from some base class of Product, Employee and Camera.  Next, loop through those types calling the CreateMap and ConvertUsing methods.

There's no type scanning to speak of which is why things like this aren't really there.  But it's not too bad to do your own type scanning as needed.

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I realized that it would take more work to write the reflection code than it would be to just explicitly map a few classes.